# Node.js Express sends 400 in requests when performing a query string containing pipes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, get

With Node `12.0.0` and express `4.16.4` when I make a request containing `|` (the character pipe) it always answer `400 bad request`.

This is a sample server:

```
var express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.all('*', function(request, response, next) {
    console.log(request)
    next();
});

app.get('/search', function (request, response) {
    response.send("yeah!");
});

var server = app.listen(8000, function() {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log('Server listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

if I perform a `GET` request like `http://localhost:8000/search?q=|` There is no log from the middleware and `400 bad request` is sent.

I need to handle requests with pipes to preserve old URLs. How can I solve it?

Comment: To confirm, does it work with other requests?

Comment: Of course, using the toy example if you perform `http://localhost:8000/search?q=somthing` you get `200` respose code and `yeah!` as message

Comment: Can you just escape `|` to `%7C`? https://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Use `encodeURIComponent()` to build your query string

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I need to handle old URLs containing pipes.

Comment: can it be caused by the use of `llhttp` instead of `http-parser` in node 12?

Comment: It is  working fine with nodev `11.11.0`, I don't know why, but issue only on appends when I use node `12.0.0`, do not have any log, request log... in server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `--http-parser=legacy` to work around this issue for now.

`node --http-parser=legacy index.js`

I had open a issue about it [HTTP response corrupted with status 400 when URL includes pipe character (`|`)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/27584)